# ReactJS Click and Hold Button

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm creating a React App which is able to shut down physical devices (like power sources etc.)
For every device, I have a shutdown button which needs to be pressed and hold for 3 seconds to activate. In addition to that, I need a animation that shows the remaining time of this 3 seconds to the user: which exactly looks like : 
http://sonsoleslp.github.io/react-click-n-hold/

However, I am getting errors when I import the CSS to my CSS file that is

```css
@-webkit-keyframes fill { 
    to {
        background-size: 100% 0; 
    }
} 

@keyframes fill { 
    to { 
        background-size: 100% 0;
    }
}

.cnh_holding button {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( white , white) rgb(255,215,235) no-repeat 0 0;
    background: linear-gradient( white , white) rgb(255,215,235) no-repeat 0 0;
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-animation: fill 2s forwards;
    animation: fill 2s forwards;
}
```

Whole CSS code is up there.

I tried changing the CSS but animation does not work this time. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Try changing "to" to "0%" and add a "100%" that tells how it should look when its complete. Can you paste your whole code also?

Comment: I have posted the whole code thnx for your answer now I will try it @MstrQKN

Comment: Your css is perfectly valid, what error is thrown ?

Answer (score 1):

It works if you add `from{}` before `to{}`

```css
@-webkit-keyframes fill { 
from {background-size: 100% 100%;}
    to {
        background-size: 100% 0; 
    }
} 

@keyframes fill { 
from {background-size: 100% 100%;}
    to { 
        background-size: 100% 0;
    }
}
.cnh_holding button {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( white , white) rgb(255,215,235) no-repeat 0 0;
    background: linear-gradient( white , white) rgb(255,215,235) no-repeat 0 0;
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-animation: fill 2s forwards;
    animation: fill 2s forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="cnh_holding"><button>CLICK</button></div>
```